# Trying to write a code which gives the strategy a buffer time before it takes the next trades

Tags: finance, pine-script, quantitative-finance

What I'm trying to achieve is a "gap" of a few candles, say 4 in this case before the next trade happens
Here nexT is the number of bars, before which the next trade should not take place
But the value of nextT always resets to 0, everytime the code runs.
What can be a possible modification to the code that the value of nexT does not reset automatically.

```
//@version=4
strategy("RSI Strategy", overlay=true)
//timeframe
//timframe
FromMonth = input(defval = 9, title = "From Month", minval = 1)
FromDay   = input(defval = 9, title = "From Day", minval = 1)
FromYear  = input(defval = 2019, title = "From Year", minval = 2000)
ToMonth   = input(defval = 11, title = "To Month", minval = 1)
ToDay     = input(defval = 23, title = "To Day", minval = 1)
ToYear    = input(defval = 2020, title = "To Year", minval = 2014) 
nexT      = input(defval=0)
gap       = input(4,defval=4)
testPeriod() =>
    (time > timestamp(FromYear, FromMonth, FromDay, 00, 00)) and (time < timestamp(ToYear, ToMonth, ToDay, 23, 59))
//Indicator
length = input( 14 )
overSold = input( 30 )
overBought = input( 70 )
price = close
vrsi = rsi(price, length)
co = crossover(vrsi, overSold)
cu = crossunder(vrsi, overBought)
//longonly
//strategy.risk.allow_entry_in(strategy.direction.long)
trade= co or cu
if(bar_index>=nexT)
    if(trade)
        if (co)
            strategy.entry("RsiLE", strategy.long, comment="RsiLE")
        if (cu)
            strategy.entry("RsiSE", strategy.short, comment="RsiSE")
        nextT= bar_index+gap
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `:=` operator for var assign in Pine:
`nextT := bar_index+gap`

Answer (score 0):

Your `nexT` variable is an input variable, so it is immutable.
That means that you cannot change it's value through code.

The solution is to create a new variable `new_nexT` which is defined with the keyword `var` and is initialized with your `nexT` input variable.

When you define a variable without the `var` keyword, it is re-initialized on every bar, so it's value is volatile.
When you define a variable with the `var` keyword, it's only initialized once, on the first bar, and keeps it's value on the subsequent bars, unless you change it's value.
To change a value for a `var` variable, you must use `:=` instead of `=`.

Using my edited code example hereunder, `new_nexT` is initialized once (because it's a `var`) and assigned the `nexT` input variable during that initialization.
A bit further in the code, `:=` is used to assign a new value to it.

```
//@version=4
strategy("RSI Strategy", overlay=true)

//timeframe
FromMonth = input(defval = 9, title = "From Month", minval = 1)
FromDay   = input(defval = 9, title = "From Day", minval = 1)
FromYear  = input(defval = 2019, title = "From Year", minval = 2000)
ToMonth   = input(defval = 11, title = "To Month", minval = 1)
ToDay     = input(defval = 23, title = "To Day", minval = 1)
ToYear    = input(defval = 2020, title = "To Year", minval = 2014) 
nexT      = input(defval = 0)
gap       = input(defval = 4)

var int new_nexT = nexT

testPeriod() =>
    (time > timestamp(FromYear, FromMonth, FromDay, 00, 00)) and (time < timestamp(ToYear, ToMonth, ToDay, 23, 59))

//Indicator
length      = input( 14 )
overSold    = input( 30 )
overBought  = input( 70 )
price       = close
vrsi        = rsi(price, length)
co          = crossover(vrsi, overSold)
cu          = crossunder(vrsi, overBought)

//longonly
//strategy.risk.allow_entry_in(strategy.direction.long)

trade = co or cu

if(bar_index >= new_nexT and trade)
    if (co)
        strategy.entry("RsiLE", strategy.long, comment="RsiLE")
    if (cu)
        strategy.entry("RsiSE", strategy.short, comment="RsiSE")
    new_nexT := bar_index + gap
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Bjorn! This strategy misses on a few borderline cases,so I was trying to write a new one but had some errors with declaration. I've posted that as a question. Can you please have a look at it?

Comment: Explained for gap=50.The Problem with the code is, it gives a gap of n candles after the condition is met. But not after it actually takes a trade. RSI is used here with 30,70 cross overs. If you add it on a Trading view chart and also plot the RSI, you'll see the problem. Ex: It shorted on 16th Nov. as rsi crossed down 70. Then it took a buffer period of 50 candles. RSI crossed down again on 21st but it continued the short as it didn't cross 30 level. But that triggered our gap condition even though it didn't take a trade. It should have taken a trade on 22nd when RSI crosses down 30 but it

Comment: - But it didn't. As the trigger on 21st was false and it took a gap of 50 candles which wasn't a requirement as there was no trade the condition was true but the trade wasn't taken because it crossed down 70 two consecutive times without crossing up 30. What I'm trying to achieve is strictly a gap of 50 candles after it takes a trade but not after the condition(trade) is true.

Comment: Asset: BTCUSDTPERP, Binance. 1H