# Trying to write a code which gives the strategy a buffer time before it takes the next trades, Problems with declarations

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to have a gap before it script takes the next trade. The previous version of the script I was working had some issueswith particular test cases. This one, tris to achieve the same functionality but I'm having some problems with the variable declarations

```
//@version=4
strategy("RSI Strategy", overlay=true)

//timeframe
FromMonth = input(defval = 9, title = "From Month", minval = 1)
FromDay   = input(defval = 9, title = "From Day", minval = 1)
FromYear  = input(defval = 2019, title = "From Year", minval = 2000)
ToMonth   = input(defval = 11, title = "To Month", minval = 1)
ToDay     = input(defval = 23, title = "To Day", minval = 1)
ToYear    = input(defval = 2020, title = "To Year", minval = 2014) 
testPeriod() =>
    (time > timestamp(FromYear, FromMonth, FromDay, 00, 00)) and (time < timestamp(ToYear, ToMonth, ToDay, 23, 59))
//Indicator
length      = input( 14 )
overSold    = input( 30 )
overBought  = input( 70 )
price       = close
vrsi        = rsi(price, length)
co          = crossover(vrsi, overSold)
cu          = crossunder(vrsi, overBought)

//For co

gap = 4
Arr_l = co ? 1 : 0
Mod_gap_l = sum(Arr_l)
buy_w_gap = Arr_l and (Mod_gap_l%gap == 0)? 1 : 0
if (buy_w_gap)
    strategy.entry("RsiLE", strategy.long, comment="RsiLE")
//for cu
Arr_s = co ? 1 : 0
Mod_gap_s = sum(Arr_s)
sell_w_gap =  Arr_s and (Mod_gap_s%gap == 0)? 1 : 0
if (sell_w_gap)
    strategy.entry("RsiSE", strategy.short, comment="RsiSE")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do with this, but I'm assuming something like this.

```
//@version=4
strategy("RSI Strategy", overlay=true)

//timeframe
FromMonth = input(defval = 9, title = "From Month", minval = 1)
FromDay   = input(defval = 9, title = "From Day", minval = 1)
FromYear  = input(defval = 2019, title = "From Year", minval = 2000)
ToMonth   = input(defval = 11, title = "To Month", minval = 1)
ToDay     = input(defval = 23, title = "To Day", minval = 1)
ToYear    = input(defval = 2020, title = "To Year", minval = 2014) 
testPeriod() =>
    (time > timestamp(FromYear, FromMonth, FromDay, 00, 00)) and (time < timestamp(ToYear, ToMonth, ToDay, 23, 59))
//Indicator
length      = input( 14 )
overSold    = input( 30 )
overBought  = input( 70 )
price       = close

var int     gap         = 4
var float   vrsi        = na
var bool    co          = na
var bool    cu          = na
var int     Mod_gap_l   = na
var int     Mod_gap_s   = na
var bool    buy_w_gap   = na
var bool    sell_w_gap  = na

vrsi        := rsi(price, length)
co          := crossover(vrsi, overSold)
cu          := crossunder(vrsi, overBought)

//For co

// Arr_l = co ? 1 : 0
// Mod_gap_l = sum(Arr_l)
Mod_gap_l := barssince(co)
buy_w_gap := (Mod_gap_l > 0) and (Mod_gap_l%gap == 0)
if buy_w_gap
    strategy.entry("RsiLE", strategy.long, comment="RsiLE")

//for cu
// Arr_s = co ? 1 : 0
// Mod_gap_s = sum(Arr_s)
Mod_gap_s   := barssince(cu) // I assume you want to use 'cu' here instead of 'co'
sell_w_gap  := (Mod_gap_s > 0) and (Mod_gap_s%gap == 0)? 1 : 0
if sell_w_gap
    strategy.entry("RsiSE", strategy.short, comment="RsiSE")
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is, Give my strategy a cool down period before it takes the next trade. Say n candles. n is the variable gap here

Comment: That was already solved in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64970980).

Comment: That one leaves some border line cases, I cross checked. So was trying to build something more robust

Comment: It's better to explain the border line cases with an example + screenshots. Your posted code in this question doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: Can I text you personally? email?

Comment: I think it's better to just explain here on StackOverflow, because there's a whole community that can help you.

Comment: Explained the border cases in comments for original question posted.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the code you provided does not represent what you are trying to achieve and the question itself is not asked in a clear way...
But I do understand what you're trying to achieve.

You can use the ta.barssince() function to count the number of bars since a condition was true.

For example (PineScript V5):

```
//Input for defining how many bars long the cooldown period is.
CoolDownPeriod = input.int(defval=5, minval=1, maxval=100, title="Cool Down 
    Period")

//Example of Buy and Sell conditions.
BuyCond  = ema1 > ema2 and ema1[1] < ema2[1]
SellCond = ema1 < ema2 and ema1[1] > ema2[1]

//If the number of bars since the sell condition is greater than the cool down 
//period then we can plot and enter a new buy trade.
if ta.barssince(SellCond) > CoolDownPeriod
    plotshape(BuyCond, style=, location=, color=, text=, textcolor=, size=)
    strategy.entry("entry", strategy.long, comment="")
if SellCond
    plotshape(SellCond, style=, location=, color=, text=, textcolor=, size=)
    strategy.close("entry", comment="")
```

Comment: I am not aware of any way to actually measure the time passed since a condition... But you can measure the number of bars passed using that code I provided. I know this is 11 months late but this is for anyone else who may have the same question.